# Objective-C, Transitioning from .nib to .storyboard

Tags: xcode, cocoa, storyboard, nib

I'm trying to update my application from using `.nibs` to the more recent `.storyboard` format on **OS X**. I'm not exactly sure what the best method of accomplishing this would be.

[image]

Currently I have both the old `MainMenu.nib` and `Main.Storyboard` in my project. It's easy enough for me to manually copy items from the `.nib` to the `.storyboard`, although how do I tell XCode to start using my `.storyboard` instead of the `.nib`? Is it possible to use both in the same project? Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: It is also possible to use both. When I've started new modules, i've simply started using storyboards instead of creating classes with .xib files. At some point if you want to refactor the whole initial flow and replace the existing xibs with a storyboard flow, you might have to do the suggested answer below. Meanwhile you can use storyboards, segues, and all the good stuff that comes with them along with xibs. Just make sure to initiate your controllers using [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:name bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: ] instead of alloc/init.

Comment: @mitrenegade, thanks - I've only used nibs and xibs, so there's a bit of an adjustment in structure that i'll need to get used to. The storyboards definitely seem like a good concept to carry over onto osx.

Answer (score 0):

> although how do I tell XCode to start using my .storyboard instead of the .nib?

If you no longer want to use *MainMenu.nib* at all, then you set the `NSMainStoryboardFile` key in your *Info.plist* (and delete the `NSMainNibFile` key). That way, the storyboard file is used at launch.

*Info.plist* keys are documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/GeneralPurposeKeys.html

Comment: Thanks for the info - One question about the the structure of `nibs` vs. `storyboards`. In my `nib`, `objects` resided on the top level (not inside any window controllers or view controllers) where multiple windows and views could easily access them. I noticed when moving the existing nib views into their new storyboard view controller homes that they could not access objects outside of the view controller. Is this normal? and is there a way for multiple views in different view controllers to access the same object?

Comment: you're right in that there's a lot of new ways to structure your IB stuff that you'll have to get used to. I work in ios dev so I'm not sure if there might be minor differences. One question would be what kind of object did you have at the top level in your nib? If anything I'd think you could share more objects, in the form of controllers, in a storyboard between multiple nibs. You might want to look into container views - you basically have subviews set as container views, and you connect these views to the controllers of your shared object as an "embed" segue.